# Getting All Paired Shortest Paths in ArcGIS network analysis at once?

Tags: arcgis-server, network-analyst, shortest-path

I have some difficulties on network analysis,I want to run shortest path algorithm,
 I  don't know how to use ArcGIS to reveal the shortest route between the appointed points on the map, and if it's possible, can I also use this software to record and calculate the number of the real road be taken as shortest route?

I have about 200 point to be the origins and destinations on the map, and I need the shortest route between these appointed points (200*200) and let them revealed on the map
And then,record and calculate the number of the real road be taken as shortest route.

but i can only have one shortest route between two points once a time if i use the toolbar, i am wondering how can i make all the shortest routes between 200 points one time? do i have to use any progamming method?

Comment: You need to have [Network Analyst](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/networkanalyst/index.html) extension to have the full power of ArcGIS Network Analysis.  Basic routing can also be done using [Utility Network](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Utility_Network_Analyst_toolbar) toolbar.

Answer (score 5):

There are two choose for you on NAServer. The NAServer is a MapServer object extension that can be used to perform network analysis in a stateless environment using ArcGIS Server.

For publishing a network analysis service you can check out this [tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00530000000w000000)...

**1.Closest Facility Analysis:** displays the best routes between incidents and facilities.

[image: Closest Facility Analysis]

**2.OD Cost Matrix:** (origin–destination (OD) cost matrix) a table that contains the network impedance from each origin to each destination.

[image: od1]

[image: od2]

and showing them in a map as openlayers, you can use ArcGIS Server Service.

```
1.Go to Home > Network(NAServer) > Route
2.Select Solve Route
3.Define your points and barriers
4.Get format as JSON
5.Read json features and add them to vector layer.
```

example NAServer is [here](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/NAServer/Route/solve). beside this you have to define stops as following structure:

```
{ 
"features"  : [
{
  "geometry" : {"x" : -122.4079, "y" : 37.78356},
  "attributes" : {"Name" : "From", "RouteName" : "Route A"}
},
{
  "geometry" : {"x" : -122.404, "y" : 37.782},
  "attributes" : {"Name" : "To", "RouteName" : "Route A"}
}
]
}
```

you can check out this example:

- result as [json](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/NAServer/Route/solve?stops=%7B%20%0D%0A%22features%22%20%20:%20%5B%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22geometry%22%20:%20%7B%22x%22%20:%20-122.4079,%20%22y%22%20:%2037.78356%7D,%0D%0A%20%20%22attributes%22%20:%20%7B%22Name%22%20:%20%22From%22,%20%22RouteName%22%20:%20%22Route%20A%22%7D%0D%0A%7D,%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22geometry%22%20:%20%7B%22x%22%20:%20-122.404,%20%22y%22%20:%2037.782%7D,%0D%0A%20%20%22attributes%22%20:%20%7B%22Name%22%20:%20%22To%22,%20%22RouteName%22%20:%20%22Route%20A%22%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&barriers=&polylineBarriers=&polygonBarriers=&outSR=4326&ignoreInvalidLocations=true&accumulateAttributeNames=&impedanceAttributeName=Time&restrictionAttributeNames=OneWay,TurnRestriction,Avoid%20passenger%20ferries,Non-routeable%20segments&attributeParameterValues=&restrictUTurns=esriNFSBAllowBacktrack&useHierarchy=true&returnDirections=true&returnRoutes=true&returnStops=false&returnBarriers=false&returnPolylineBarriers=false&returnPolygonBarriers=false&directionsLanguage=en-US&directionsStyleName=NA%20Desktop&outputLines=esriNAOutputLineTrueShape&findBestSequence=false&preserveFirstStop=true&preserveLastStop=true&useTimeWindows=true&startTime=1227663551096&outputGeometryPrecision=&outputGeometryPrecisionUnits=esriUnknownUnits&directionsTimeAttributeName=Time&directionsLengthUnits=esriNAUMiles&f=pjson)
- result as [html](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/NAServer/Route/solve?stops=%7B%20%0D%0A%22features%22%20%20:%20%5B%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22geometry%22%20:%20%7B%22x%22%20:%20-122.4079,%20%22y%22%20:%2037.78356%7D,%0D%0A%20%20%22attributes%22%20:%20%7B%22Name%22%20:%20%22From%22,%20%22RouteName%22%20:%20%22Route%20A%22%7D%0D%0A%7D,%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22geometry%22%20:%20%7B%22x%22%20:%20-122.404,%20%22y%22%20:%2037.782%7D,%0D%0A%20%20%22attributes%22%20:%20%7B%22Name%22%20:%20%22To%22,%20%22RouteName%22%20:%20%22Route%20A%22%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&barriers=&polylineBarriers=&polygonBarriers=&outSR=4326&ignoreInvalidLocations=true&accumulateAttributeNames=&impedanceAttributeName=Time&restrictionAttributeNames=OneWay,TurnRestriction,Avoid%20passenger%20ferries,Non-routeable%20segments&attributeParameterValues=&restrictUTurns=esriNFSBAllowBacktrack&useHierarchy=true&returnDirections=true&returnRoutes=true&returnStops=false&returnBarriers=false&returnPolylineBarriers=false&returnPolygonBarriers=false&directionsLanguage=en-US&directionsStyleName=NA%20Desktop&outputLines=esriNAOutputLineTrueShape&findBestSequence=false&preserveFirstStop=true&preserveLastStop=true&useTimeWindows=true&startTime=1227663551096&outputGeometryPrecision=&outputGeometryPrecisionUnits=esriUnknownUnits&directionsTimeAttributeName=Time&directionsLengthUnits=esriNAUMiles&f=html)

you should know this the link is so long:

> _http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/NAServer/Route/solve?stops={+%0D%0A%22features%22++%3A+[%0D%0A{%0D%0A++%22geometry%22+%3A+{%22x%22+%3A+-122.4079%2C+%22y%22+%3A+37.78356}%2C%0D%0A++%22attributes%22+%3A+{%22Name%22+%3A+%22From%22%2C+%22RouteName%22+%3A+%22Route+A%22}%0D%0A}%2C%0D%0A{%0D%0A++%22geometry%22+%3A+{%22x%22+%3A+-122.404%2C+%22y%22+%3A+37.782}%2C%0D%0A++%22attributes%22+%3A+{%22Name%22+%3A+%22To%22%2C+%22RouteName%22+%3A+%22Route+A%22}%0D%0A}%0D%0A]%0D%0A}%0D%0A&barriers=&polylineBarriers=&polygonBarriers=&outSR=4326&ignoreInvalidLocations=true&accumulateAttributeNames=&impedanceAttributeName=Time&restrictionAttributeNames=OneWay%2CTurnRestriction%2CAvoid+passenger+ferries%2CNon-routeable+segments&attributeParameterValues=&restrictUTurns=esriNFSBAllowBacktrack&useHierarchy=true&returnDirections=true&returnRoutes=true&returnStops=false&returnBarriers=false&returnPolylineBarriers=false&returnPolygonBarriers=false&directionsLanguage=en-US&directionsStyleName=NA+Desktop&outputLines=esriNAOutputLineTrueShape&findBestSequence=false&preserveFirstStop=true&preserveLastStop=true&useTimeWindows=true&startTime=1227663551096&outputGeometryPrecision=&outputGeometryPrecisionUnits=esriUnknownUnits&directionsTimeAttributeName=Time&directionsLengthUnits=esriNAUMiles&f=html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use OD Cost Matrix tool of the Network Analyst extension. It calculates 200*200 lines follwing the shortest path, but I do not know how to show them on the map nor how to calculate the number of the real road be taken as shortest route.